# Higher gerbes and cohomologies

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Suppose $X$ is a scheme over a field $k$ and $G$ a group scheme over $k$ (may assume commutative), one can talk about $G$-torsors and $G$-gerbes over $X$ and their isomorphism classes are given by $H^1(X,G)$ and $H^2(X,G)$ (calculated in suitable Grothendieck topologies) respectively. These have been well written in the literature. I think the similar results for higher gerbes and higher cohomologies also hold but I could not find any reference. Could someone suggest a reference for it? Thanks.

Comment: Intro + Section 7.2.2 in Lurie "Higher Topos Theory"?

Comment: Corollary $7.2.2.27$ in above reference. Let $\mathfrak{X}$ be an $\infty$-topos, and $n \geq 2$, and $A$ an abelian group object of $Disc(\mathfrak{X})$. There is a canonical bijection of $H^{n+1} (\mathfrak{X}; A)$ with the set of equivalence classes of $n$-gerbes on $\mathfrak{X}$ banded by $A$..

Comment: @PiotrAchinger, thanks for mentioning Lurie's paper. I was kinda aware of the paper but unfortunately I'm not very familiar with the language of the infinity topos....